# How to get the SDP information from sip class (in java)?

Tags: java, sip, jmf, sdp

I am implementing a call-bridging application over Sailfin.
 The SIP signalling is running fine. But I need the Source and Destination RTP media port for audioCapture.

How to get the port information from the INVOKE content (SDP part)? Which specific method will be used?

Answer (score 0):

Since sailfin is an implementation of JSR-289, it does not understand SIP content. You can get at the SDP by reading the `SipServletRequest` and `SipServletResponse` contents using `SipServletMessage.getContent()` which returns an `Object`.

Unless for proof-of-concept, I strongly recommend delegating media handling to a media proxy even for a simple B2BUA app. There are many out there, I happen to like [this one](http://mediaproxy.ag-projects.com/) which is built by the same group that built OpenSIPS.